# Why I can't pass one argument to sub

Tags: perl

input is directory name and output is text file name which is in the directory and the file's name, line count, word count. 
when I checked this program, i could know when second sub is working, $_ is nothing like "".

how should i fix it ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $dir = <STDIN>;
chomp($dir); # remove '\n'(new-line character) from directory address
opendir(dirHandle, "$dir"); 
my @arr = readdir(dirHandle);
close(dirHandle);
foreach(@arr){
    if($_ =~ /.txt/){
        print "File Name : $_\n";       
        my $tmp = $_;
        print "Line Numb : ".&how_many_lines($_)."\n";
        print "Word Numb : ".&how_many_words($_)."\n\n";
    }
}
sub how_many_lines{
    open(FILE, "$_") || die "Can't open '$_': $!";
    my $cnt=0;
    while(<FILE>){ 
        $cnt++;
    }
    close(FILE);
    return $cnt;
}
sub how_many_words{
    open(TEXT, "$_") || die "Can't open '$_': $!";
    # error! printed "Can't open ''" : No such file or directory
    my $cnt=0;
    while(<TEXT>){
        my @tmp = split(/ /, $_);
        my $num = @tmp;
        $cnt += $num;
    }
    close(TEXT);
    return $cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to the first argument of a sub with `$_`. It should be `$_[0]`, the first element of array `@_`, which is the list of arguments.

The most idiomatic (not to be confused with idiotic) way of retrieving arguments in the sub is this:

```
my $filename = shift;  # shift uses @_ automatically without arguments
```

Perl allows the same names for scalars, arrays and hashes: `$foo`, `@foo`, `%foo` are different entities. When you index the array `@foo` with zero, it becomes `$foo[0]`. Which is not the same as `$foo`.